# CREATE sql syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

Not sure where the problem is. I removed the constraints which I was unsure about but that solved nothing and I cannot find where my syntax fails. Can anybody help? [The Syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWlV6.png) and 
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMP91.png)

Syntax:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblPlayerStats(
    PlayerStatsID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    PlayerID INT NOT NULL, 
    Position VARCHAR(5), 
    Total_Rec INT, 
    Rec_YDS INT, 
    Rec_AVG INT, 
    TDs INT, 
    TCKL INT, 
    FF INT, 
    Interceptions INT, 
    SCKS NUM, 
    Pass_YDS INT, 
    Rush_YDS INT, 
    PlayerRank INT, 
    CONSTRAINT tblPlayerStats_pk RIMARY KEY (PlayerStatsID), 
    CONSTRAINT tblPlayerStats_fk FOREIGN KEY (PlayerID) REFERENCES tblPlayer (PlayerID))")

Error: Traceback (most recent call last):

File "CreateNFLplayerstats.py", line 13, in <module>
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblPlayerStats(PlayerStatsID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOTCKL INT, FF INT, Interceptions INT, SCKS NUM, Pass_YDS INT, Rush_YDS INT, PlayerRank INT, CONST) REFERENCES tblPlayer (PlayerID))")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandl
raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: **(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the man Rush_YDS INT, PlayerRank INT, CONSTRAINT tblPlayerStats_pk RI' at line 1")**
```

Comment: Post your code/error here.  We do not go "outside" to look at your problem.

Comment: i am new to Stackoverflow so i am not sure how to make the image visible without having to select the link

Comment: images of code/errors are also useless. cut/paste the actual code/error TEXT.

Comment: my apologies, i have added the syntax and error

Comment: You're missing the `P` in `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with python. it's purely a mysql syntax error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error states there is an error near ‘NUM.  That is because “NUM” is not a type.  Change the type to “NUMERIC”